# Maple matrix multiplication freezes system

Tags: matrix, freeze, maple

I have problem multiplying matrices in Maple. My PC just freezes forever and i have to do hard reset when i try to execute the code below, which looks kinda trivial for me. And I dont know how to debug it. I tried using MatrixMatrixMultiplication with the same result.

```
A := Matrix(8, 17, [[-1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, -1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 1]]);
Y := ArrayTools[Diagonal]([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 0.63e-3]);
A . Y;
```

So, your help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Those commands produce the expected result, quickly and without problems, on my Maple 2018.0 on 64bit Linux. What version and OS are you using? Does it still go wrong if you instead do `A . Matrix(Y)` ?

Comment: I'm using Maple 2017.3 on Windows 8. Still had to hard reset after trying your suggestion. What i narrowed it down to is the last element of the diagonal matrix, if it equals 17 for example, everything goes smoothly.

Comment: If all this was entered in 2D Input mode, literally, it would be interesting to know if it also went bonkers when entered as plaintext in 1D Notation in an Execution Group. It also works ok for me in Maple 2017.2 on 64bit Linux. Is your Maple 64bit or 32bit? (`kernelopts(version)` shows it.) Does it also crash if you enter that last diagonal entry as 0.00063 ? Do you have any special language pack installed (where say a comma denotes a decimal period)?

Comment: It is 64bit version and no language pack. Also checked 0.00063 value and got the same result. I also feel this process is kinda painful for my PC. I worked around it by finding on MaplePrimes a procedure that multiplies matrices via row-column multiplication. That one worked fine for me. The only other mention of the same problem, that I found and replicated was https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1178170/matrix-multiplication-in-maple